# Logitech C310 webcam video problems

Tags: 11.10, webcam, logitech

I've just installed a Logitech C310 webcam on my Ubuntu Oneiric machine, and I've got several problems. When I use cheese, if I set it to use the higher resolutions, the picture contain shadows and has distorted colors. [image: 1280x960] Only with lower resolutions the picture looks okay. [image: 800x448]
The above photos were taken with cheese.

In addition, the camera's internal microphone didn't always work. When using it through pulseaudio, the sounds were fast and with high pitch. When using it directly through alsa it sounded fine.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I moved the sound part to a [new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78910/logitech-c310-audio-problems).

Comment: This cam should work out of the box, have you tried guvcview (in the software centre).

Comment: It works in guvcview, even in higher resolutions, except when choosing the format YV12 or YU12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution was helpful for me: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cheese/+bug/838739/comments/16

> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libv4l
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install libv4l-0 libv4l-dev
> ```
>
> In my case it solved all my problems (cheese, gst-launch-0.10) except
>   one. Since I'm running a 64 bits system, I keep having a problem with
>   Skype, even after updating the i386 libraries (sudo apt-get install
>   libv4l-0:i386). However, with the help of v4l2ucp you can change the
>   saturation pattern and get a much more reasonable output.

Answer (score 1):

This is a confirmed bug, I believe someone is working on the solution, (not me I am also affected)
For status updates check:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cheese/+bug/838739