# Logitech C310 audio problems

Tags: 11.10, sound, pulseaudio, webcam, logitech

I just installed a Logitech C310 webcam, on my onieric system, and I have a problem with it's audio. When recording sound from the webcam's source, the resuult is played very fast, in a very high pitch. I believe it has something to do with pulseaudio, since when I tried recording directly from alsa (by using audacity), the result was fine.

EDIT: I checked it further, and the problem occurs only after I switch between different users.

EDIT: I've also found a similar [bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=663583#c9) reported on Fedora.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem and I found the the solution [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1860715.html)

Open Terminal and use the next:

```
gedit $HOME/.pulse/daemon.conf
```

and put the following line on the file:

> default-sample-rate = 16000

save it, and then restart pulseaudio as a user with the following command

```
pulseaudio --kill && pulseaudio --start
```

Do this for every user.

Comment: Thanks, I did this for every user, and now the recording is played back fine for one of the users, but the other user can't select the webcam source in sound settings.

Comment: You can add that line to the `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`file and this setting will work for all users in the system.