# (18.04) Recording-Problems with my USB-Microphone

Tags: usb, 18.04, microphone, ffmpeg

When I record a Sound from my Logitech Webcam the Voice is like a "Mickey Mouse" - in "Cheese" the recorded Video are ok! Please help me!
I have the Problem with Ubuntu 18.04 and the same in Kubuntu 18.04!
Thanks very much!

Greetings, Claus Gronald

Comment: No magic solution, but I had the same issue. I solved it by unplugging the webcam and plugging it in again.

Answer (score 12):

The problem is same ancient as Ubuntu. It has the name "Logitech webcam microphone chipmunk sound". Looks like the problem has resurrected with Ubuntu 18.04 with its  4.15 kernel.

The well-known old workaround for the bug ["Logitech camera microphone makes "chipmunk" sound"](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/843431/) has worked for my Logitech C270 webcam like a charm.

You have to disable USB autosuspend at kernel boot parameters. Open `/etc/default/grub` file with a text editor, let it be `nano` for instance:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

and find there line with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. Add `usbcore.autosuspend=-1` to kernel parameters, i.e. replace the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

with this one

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash usbcore.autosuspend=-1"
```

Save changes and apply it to your system with grub update:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot your computer and the chipmunk (Mickey Mouse) sound problem has to dissappear.

Comment: This fix worked great for me but out of curiosity I would love any  information regarding whether it is the same bug as 2011, how something like this pops back up, why did the unplug/plug option work for MikeRSpencer?

Comment: @Dennis The problem is caused by absence of `driver_info` for the popular Logitech webcams in latest Ubuntu 18.04 kernel `drivers/usb/core/quirks.c`, take a look: [https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/CQBhn2w97j/](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/CQBhn2w97j/) - the file should be patched like this: [https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/843431/comments/37](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/843431/comments/37) Regarding MikeRSpencer's replug it's difficult to say something without additional information. The replug doesn't work in my case.

Comment: You're awesome, thanks for the explanation, fixed my problem with Logitech C270.

Comment: I lol'd so hard reading "Logitech webcam microphone chipmunk sound". Anyways, +1 for the answer, definitely works here on Debian 10.

Comment: Worked for Logitech C210 in ubutntu 20.04

Answer (score 1):

Doing this worked for me:

```bsh
mkdir $HOME/.pulse/
echo "default-sample-rate = 16000" >> $HOME/.pulse/daemon.conf
pulseaudio --kill && pulseaudio --start
```

Then I also restarted computer.

Reference: [Logitech C310 audio problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78910/logitech-c310-audio-problems)

Answer (score 0):

[usbreset](https://github.com/jkulesza/usbreset) can be used for virtually unplugging and plugging the camera, instead of crawling under your desk after starting a video conference.

1. Download The code

   ```
   sudo apt-ǵet install git
   git clone https://github.com/jkulesza/usbreset.git
   ```
2. Compile it

   ```
   cd usbreset
   gcc usbreset.c -o usbreset
   ```
3. Move it somewhere on your path

   ```
   sudo cp usbreset /usr/local/bin
   ```
4. Create a script for easy execution

   - Execute lsusb, to find your camera vendor id.

     ```
     lsusb
     [...]
     Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:0819 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C210
     [...]
     ```
   - Write the following script in a file `reset-webcam.sh`. Replace my product id with yours

     ```
      #!/bin/bash
      sudo usbreset "/dev/bus/usb/$(lsusb -d 046d:0819 | sed 's/:/ /' | cut -d \  -f 2,4 | sed 's/ /\//')"
     ```
   - Give it execution rights and move it to your PATH

     ```
     chmod +x reset-webcam.sh
     mv reset-webcam.sh /usr/local/bin
     ```

When you need to fix the chipmunk, execute `reset-webcam.sh` from a console.