# Is the Logitech C310 webcam compatible?

Tags: 11.10, drivers, webcam, logitech

Does the Logitech C310 webcam work in Ubuntu 11.10? Do we require any drivers to install that webcam on Ubuntu 11.10?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have found two previously-asked questions here on Ask Ubuntu that look like they would be relevant to you:

- [Logitech C310 webcam video problems](https://askubuntu.com/q/78452/18612)
- [Logitech C310 audio problems](https://askubuntu.com/q/78910/18612)

The good news is your camera should be expected to work out of the box, more or less. No manual driver installation will be necessary.

That being said, this particular model does seem to have some video and especially audio issues on 11.10.

Answer (score 0):

My Logitech C310 audio did not work with 11.10 .  Lots of other solutions did not work, including loading some backport module, because I couldn't find it.

What did work is here:

http://www.matthartley.com/audio-problems-with-skype-for-ubuntu/

Basically load pavucontrol, start skype, look at the recording tab, set the audio to the c310.