# How to install a Logitech c310 webcam?

Tags: 11.10, drivers, webcam, logitech

I bought a new Logitech C310 webcam. I don't know how to install it on Ubuntu. I am trying to install this software through the terminal window.

```
wine /media/LWS_2_0/Setup.exe
```

but its showing as

```
fixme:ole:TLB_ReadTypeLib Header type magic 0x00905a4d not supported.
err:ole:TLB_ReadTypeLib Loading of typelib L"Z:\\media\\LWS_2_1\\MSetup.exe" failed with error 0
```

and it opens a window with data as

> We have detected you have connected your webcam to a USB1.1 port,for
>   the best performance and full feature set,we suggest using a USB2.0
>   port

I tried this all the USB ports available in my system. It's showing the same error.

Please tell me how to install this webcam on ubuntu 11.10.

Thanks for reading.

### Edit:

The cam is working with all softwares like cheese which are available in Software Center, but the main problem is the webcam consists of controllers and effects by default along with the webcam if we install the Software got along with the webcam. I already installed the same webcam on Windows. It's working fine with all effects and controllers like zoom out zoom in and pixel range selection, wide screen or standard and all these. But in Ubuntu it's just working without any control of those. If I want to go for 720p or 480p its not getting possible here. So this is the problem i got with this in Ubuntu.
Does anyone know how it is possible to add those controls in Ubuntu?

Comment: This cam should work out of the box, have you tried guvcview (in the software centre)

Answer (score 3):

What you want is to use software that comes with webcam, that can't be done since that software is made for windows (by Logitech decision), not Linux. However there is good software for Linux, for example guvcview:

```
sudo apt-get install guvcview
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that using the Windows installer will help. If you have Cheese installed on your system, check if you can see video. Here's other that have gotten this to work by plugging it in:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1688464

Comment: Its working with all softwares like cheese which are available in software center.but the main problem is the webcam consits of controllers and effects by default along with the webcam if we install the Software got along with the webcam.I already install the same webcam on windows.its working fine with all effects and controllers like zoom out zoom in and pixel range selection ,wide screen or standard and all these.but in ubuntu its just working without any controls all those.If I want to go for 720p or 480p its not getting possible here.So this is the problem i got with this in ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

This webcam should work out of the box in Ubuntu, you don't need to install anything, install a webcam program like [Cheese](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/cheese) (Click to install) and try it out.

Comment: Its working with all softwares like cheese which are available in software center.but the main problem is the webcam consits of controllers and effects by default along with the webcam if we install the Software got along with the webcam.I already install the same webcam on windows.its working fine with all effects and controllers like zoom out zoom in and pixel range selection ,wide screen or standard and all these.but in ubuntu its just working without any controls all those.If I want to go for 720p or 480p its not getting possible here.So this is the problem i got with this in ubuntu.

Comment: When i try to install the CD which they provided along with webcam its showing the error as i posted in my question.How to install that CD in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem for me is that you are using a USB 2.0 device on USB 1.1 ports.
Are you using a USB hub or alike ?

Can you post the output of lsusb please ?

In terminal

```
lsusb
```

I agree with Mordoc and Jorge about the software.

You can also check if the driver is loaded using :`lsmod|grep pwc`
Pwc is a driver widely used for Logitech webcams.

Finally, here is a question about this webcam and Ubuntu containing links to compatibilty and usage questions.
[Is the Logitech C310 webcam compatible?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82814/is-the-logitech-c310-webcam-compatible)

Comment: The Logitech C310 is a modern webcam. It does not need device drivers, it use USB video device class.

Answer (score 0):

Logitech is NOT compatible with Linux: however, it will work as a cam, but very few features. `gcuviewer` should be able to control it tho: i use a `AF orb` with  `guvcview` and it has full controls available.

But under `wine`, theres no way to get past the error in setting up the control program. I've spoken to support at logitech. They seemed surprised it worked at all on a Linux system, especially one like Puppy [i use Lucid, compatible with Ubuntu] The problem isn't the camera, its the program. But the  `guvcview` will give you full control.

Comment: I have a c270 and zoom controls, for example, are not available on guvcview in my Ubuntu 12.04.