# How can i get instant messenger with my logitech webcam C110?

Tags: webcam, logitech

I'm new in LINUX, I'd install UBUNTU. I have a Logitech webcam C110, I think UBUNTU can use coz in the installation ask if I want get photo for image user; I'd install pidgin (instant messenger for internet). I dont know how to use webcam in pidgin and facebook, I don't know if I need config somethig in the webcam or if its problem of the programs (config or maybe use other different program), or maybe I need change my webcam

Answer (score 1):

I too brought c110 webcam.

From the below link, choose "cheese" suggested by "Jorge Castro".

[How to install a Logitech c310 webcam?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82897/how-to-install-a-logitech-c310-webcam)
and give a try. for me its working fine. Can't use effects effectively. all other are good. Thanks to Jorge Castro.